# Get Azure DevOps Metrics into Elatic Search Database using its REST API?

Tags: azure, rest, elasticsearch, azure-devops, kibana

I would like to analyze some metrics from a Team in my Azure DevOps Organization using Kibana along with some other data. Therefore I need to import all commits into the elastic search database. However, according to elastic’s integration page https://www.elastic.co/de/integrations?solution=all-solutions they only support Acquisition of data from Azure’s infrastructure portfolio not their DevOps product.
This is why I thought about gathering the data using DevOps’s REST-API which I would call on a daily basis.

My Question: Is there a more optimal way? Has someone already done something similar?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check [Content Sources](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/workplace-search/current/workplace-search-content-sources.html):

> Workplace Search can ingest data from many different content sources.
> A content source is usually a third-party service like GitHub, Google
> Drive, or Dropbox. **You can also build your own connectors using
> Custom API sources**, which allows you to create unique content
> repositories on the platform and send any data to Workplace Search via
> uniquely identifiable endpoints.

Since Workplace Search doesn't support DevOps, you could check [Connecting custom sources](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/workplace-search/current/workplace-search-custom-api-sources.html). And work with [Commits - Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) API to retrieve git commits for a project:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=6.0
```